# many to many EF7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Models:

```
public partial class Film
{
    public int FilmID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int GenreID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Film> Films { get; set; }
}
```

OnModelCreating using EF6

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Film>()
                    .HasMany(e => e.Genres)
                    .WithMany(e => e.Films)
                    .Map(m => m.ToTable("Genre_Film").MapLeftKey("Films_IdFilm").MapRightKey("Genres_IdGenre"));
}
```

I use SQLite. How I can do the same using EF7?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The docs for EF7 says how this can be achived: http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many

> ```
>         modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
>             .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
>             .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
>             .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId);
> ```

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);

        public class PostTag
        {
          public int PostId { get; set; }
          public Post Post { get; set; }
          public int TagId { get; set; }
          public Tag Tag { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

The mapping API will change in EF 7. There has been a proposal for a more [intuitive one to many API](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Entity-Framework-Design-Meeting-Notes---July-31,-2014). There is a short word on many to many there:

> We expect the many-to-many API to be very similar to the one-to-many and one-to-one APIs.

But it's not yet implemented in the current source. In a context created for tests it says:

```
// TODO: Many-to-many
//modelBuilder.Entity<TSupplier>().ForeignKeys(fk => fk.ForeignKey<TProduct>(e => e.SupplierId));
```

That's about all I can find about it.

I surely hope that EF7 will be backward compatible in this area.

Answer (score 2):

You can also accomplish the new table without creating a new object. This can be done via the Fluent API with the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Film>()
        .HasMany(f => f.Genres)
        .WithMany(g => g.Films)
        .UsingEntity(t => t.ToTable("GenreFilms"));
}
```