# How handle these two models in code first approach using Entity Framework 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, join, entity-framework-core

### Problem

I am coding proof of concept ASP.NET 5 MVC6 that will simulate a library. I am using CTP6 and beta3.

How to define their relationship in Entity Framework 7 using code first approach?

Shelf and Books need a join table. As I see it, this application will consider one shelf at a time and the books on that self. In other words, one shelf has a one to many relationship with books.

### Models

**Shelf model:**

```
public class Shelf
{
    public int ShelfId { get; set; }

    public string ShelfName { get; set; }

    public ShelfType MyProperty { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

}
```

**Book model:**

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public string BookName { get; set; }

    public string BookAuthor { get; set; }

    public string BookGenre { get; set; }

    public DateTime BookPublishedDate { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

}
```

### Goal

I would like to implement something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx) in ASP.NET 5. Since TPH and other features are not yet implemented in EF7, am I on the right track?

In other words, I am thinking the following:

- ShelfBookViewModel (after all I need a view model to show a shelf and the books, or the book and be able to nagivate back to the shelf). I probably will just name it ShelfBook. This seems to be the wrong approach.
- I would prefer EF7 being able to figure out I have a join and creating viewmodels for separate concerns. Otherwise, this is a violation of SOLID code practices. Something like given below (from the link earlier).
- Join tables have not been implemented in EF7 yet and I am asking in vain?

I have not been able to get the following to work as shown below:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Shelf>() 
            .HasMany(p => p.Shelfs) 
            .WithMany(t => t.Books) 
            .Map(mc => 
               { 
                   mc.ToTable("ShelfJoinBook"); 
                   mc.MapLeftKey("ShelfId"); 
                   mc.MapRightKey("BookId"); 
               });
```

Thank you for your time in reading my question. I hope others find this useful.

Comment: In this scenario would there ever be a reason for an instance of a specific book to appear on more than one shelf, or will it always be one shelf has many books, but a book will not appear on many shelves?

Comment: I think you define a boundary case. What if a library buys two books and puts them in different places? I feel, as far as this application is concerned, we would treat it as a second book. So I feel that we will always have one shelf with many books. It will be possible to check out the book in the future and move it around.

Comment: AFAIK many to many has simply not yet been implemented in EF7. Stick to the explicit junction class.

Comment: whaaa?? "Shelf and Books need a join table." "shelf has a one to many relationship with books." You realize these are contradictory, right? You only need Join table for many-to-many, not one-to-many. If you truly just need one-to-many, accept @Pynt's answer, edit your question to remove "join table" (including from the title), and move on.

Comment: @GertArnold: ?? many-to-many support has been there since at least EF 4: `class Course { int Id { get; set; } ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } }` and `class Student { int Id { get; set; } ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } }` will generate a table equivalent to `class CourseStudents { int CourseId { get; set; } int StudentId { get; set; } }` without the benefit of having an actual `CourseStudents` table available in your model (you can always add one later, if you need to add any other properties to the `CourseStudents` relation).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28382959/861716

Comment: @GertArnold: thanks for the heads-up ... searching each code base, `CollectionNavigationBuilder` (EF7) has a `WithOne` but no `WithMany`, whereas `ManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration` (EF6) has a `WithMany` returning a `ManyToManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration` ... likewise with unit tests dealing with `HasMany().WithMany()` (i.e., exists in EF6, not in EF7). Looks like it's time to put EF7 back on the shelf until they at least get to Alpha, much less Beta. Seems OP might be trying to use it for production code?

Comment: @JohnCastleman Yes, back on the shelf - or shelves :)

Comment: @JohnCastleman Not at this time. I would like to use it for production code in the future, but at the moment it is a proof of concept application.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question about many-to-many, you should define your mapping as follows (and, necessarily, update your model classes):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Shelf>() 
    .HasMany(p => p.Books) 
    .WithMany(t => t.Shelves) // doesn't exist 
    .Map(mc => 
       { 
           mc.ToTable("BookShelves"); 
           mc.MapLeftKey("ShelfId"); 
           mc.MapRightKey("BookId"); 
       });
```

which would require you to add an `ICollection<Shelf> Shelves { get; set; }` to `Book`. But, if you did so you'd then have the following (this is my [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version of your example):

```
public class Shelf
{
    public int ShelfId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Shelf> Shelves { get; set; }
}
```

and then you'd no longer need the mapping anyway, since EF would generate all the relations for you by convention, including the join table that would be visible only in the database itself.

However – from your actual model classes and your discussion around them – it appears you really only need one-to-many, in which case, you should accept Pynt's answer, and ignore mine.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold) in comments, EF7 does not currently (no longer?) supports generated join tables, which means we'll have to roll our own, which is [probably better anyway](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/).

Here's a way I think I might do my own, simple, join tables from now on, if EF will no longer do them for me (warning — I'm just trying to close the loop on this issue ... I'm not bothering to try this in a compiler, so YMMV):

```
public class Shelf
{
    public int ShelfId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookShelf> BookShelves { get; set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<Book> Books
    {
        get
        {
            return BookShelves.Where(s => s.ShelfId == ShelfId)
                              .Select(s => s.Book);
        }
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookShelf> BookShelves { get; set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<Shelf> Shelves
    {
        get
        {
            return BookShelves.Where(s => s.BookId == BookId)
                              .Select(s => s.Shelf);
        }
    }
}

public class BookShelf
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BookId")]
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int ShelfId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ShelfId")]
    public Shelf Shelf { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I still appreciate the time you took to answer my question. I will have a many to many relationship in the future. I appreciate your honesty and direct approach to commenting on my question. I have accepted your suggestions and also gave you an upvote. Much appreciated sir.

Comment: I've edited this question to include a tag for entity-framework-7 ... which means my answer will no longer work (as I put in a comment to the OP, the object returned by `HasMany` does not support a `WithMany` method in EF7, only a `WithOne`). Looks like I need to finally follow [Jimmy Bogard](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/author/jimmybogard/)'s [advice](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/) and always "roll my own" join tables from now on -- I'll update this answer to show that.

Answer (score 1):

I tackle similar situations like this, though it may not fit your needs. I use data annotations as I've not bothered to learn how to setup the Foreign Key via the lambda mapping.  With the below setup you can have one instance of a book per shelf, and the shelves can have many books. I've moved the relationship properties to the bottom of the classes for easy visualization.

Shelf model:

```
public class Shelf
{
    public int ShelfId { get; set; }

    public string ShelfName { get; set; }

    public ShelfType MyProperty { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Book model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public string BookName { get; set; }

    public string BookAuthor { get; set; }

    public string BookGenre { get; set; }

    public DateTime BookPublishedDate { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public int ShelfId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ShelfId")]
    public Shelf Shelf { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try in the next few days Pynt. I gave reputation in gratitude for your thorough answer. If this works, I'll be sure to mark as the answer.