# EF7 Add item to table with many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables with many to many relations, so I created 3rd table as join table, since EF7 will not create it automatically.

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Categorization> Categorizations { get; set; }
}

class Categorization
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Categorization> Categorizations { get; set; }
}
```

So if I want to insert/seed new records in to Products, I'm doing like this:

```
db.Products.AddRange(products); //where products = List<Product>
db.Categories.AddRange(categories);

db.SaveChanges();

db.Categories.ToList() //not using where class since tables are empty initially
    .ForEach(c => db.Products.ToList()
    .ForEach(p => db.Categorizations
    .Add(new Categorization() { CategoryId = c.Id, ProductsId = p.Id })));

db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there any effective and simple way to do the same? Thank you.

Comment: The edited top answer has writing your own join pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837659/how-handle-these-two-models-in-code-first-approach-using-entity-framework-7

Comment: @mariocatch Thanks. i understand that part. but how to Insert/update items? sorry i'm new to ef.

Comment: Inserting and saving the context is just a matter of editing items in the context and calling `SaveChanges` on it.

Comment: you do not need to call savechanges twice. also, you do not need to handle the Categorization class yourself, EF created its own junction table upon model creation, you are having two junction tables now (unless you do not have navigation properties between them).

Comment: @DevilSuichiro you are talking about EF 6, in EF7 it will not create and handle junction tables automatically

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue in EF7.

Comment: No.. i end up with Joining table and manual updates.. but there is a development in progress for this feature. may in RC-2